# Google chart Y axis not in scale with chart bar

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I have been playing with google charts for the first time. I have created a graph that can be viewed at

[Google chart link](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxr=0,0,20&chxt=y&chbh=50&chm=N,000000,0,-1,11&chd=t:0.4356,0.3562,0.4834,0.575,0.673,0.6091&chs=500x120&chco=FF3300%7C0000FF&chd=t:5,15&chl=freightmax%7Cstols)

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxr=0,0,20&chxt=y&chbh=50&chm=N,000000,0,-1,11&chd=t:0.4356,0.3562,0.4834,0.575,0.673,0.6091&chs=500x120&chco=FF3300|0000FF&chd=t:5,15&chl=freightmax|stols
```

The graph displays however the scale of the Y chart axis and the bar chart itself is not in proportion as per image below:

[image: Google Chart Image]

If you see the value of the Stols bar is 15 which is correct, however according to the y axis the value is around 3 or 4.

Any ideas how I can correct this?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan Smith

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding scale parameter **chds=0,20** should help

`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxr=0,0,20&chxt=y&chbh=50&chm=N,000000,0,-1,11&chd=t:0.4356,0.3562,0.4834,0.575,0.673,0.6091&chs=500x120&chco=FF3300|0000FF&chd=t:5,15&chl=freightmax|stols&chds=0,20`

Reference: [Google chart parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_params.html)